# sqlalchemy: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'insert'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pylons

I was playing around making a simple haiku site using sqlalchemy and pylons. It basically takes a haiku, writes it to a database, and displays the haiku. The problem appears when I get the data from the form and try and write it to a database, Pylons give me this error: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'insert' after I run this line of code: ins = self.haiku_table.insert(values=form_dict)

Main Code:

```
import logging

from pylons import request, response, session, tmpl_context as c
from pylons.controllers.util import abort, redirect_to

from myku.lib.base import BaseController, render
from sqlalchemy.sql import select
import meta
import myku.lib.helpers as h

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class IndexController(BaseController):
    def __init__(self):
        self.haiku_table = meta.haiku_table
        self.conn = meta.engine.connect()
        BaseController.__init__(self)

    def index(self, genre, title):
        ss = select([self.haiku_table], self.haiku_table.c.genre==str(genre).lower(),  self.haiku_table.c.title==str(title).lower())
       result = self.conn.execute(ss)
       return result

    def new_haiku(self):
       return render('/newku.html')

    def submit(self):
        title = request.params.get('title')
        haiku = request.params.get('haiku')
        genre = request.params.get('genre')
        author = request.params.get('author')
        form_dict = {'title': title, 'haiku': haiku, 'genre': genre, 'author': author}
        ins = self.haiku_table.insert(values=form_dict)
        result = self.conn.execute(ins)
        return res
```

and the code for the meta file:

```
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import schema, types

metadata = schema.MetaData()

haiku_table = ('haiku', metadata,
               schema.Column('title', types.Text(), primary_key=True),
               schema.Column('haiku', types.Text()),
               schema.Column('genre', types.Text()),
               schema.Column('author', types.Text())
               )

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///F:\\MyKu\\myku\\haiku')
metadata.bind = engine

metadata.create_all(checkfirst=True)
```

Any ideas?
I have no clue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it looks like you're creating `haiku_table` and not doing anything else to it before trying to use the .insert function which obviously is not part of a tuple

Looks like when you create a table with SQLAlchemy, you want the format:

```
haiku_table = Table('haiku', metadata,
           schema.Column('title', types.Text(), primary_key=True),
           .... etc
           )
```

You will need to import `Table` from the sqlachlemy module as well.

This makes haiku_table be a Table instance of SQLAlchemy and not simply a tuple. I think that's all you're missing.

Comment: Cant believe I missed that thanks!, btw Table is part of schema so its schema.Table